# Can i create a custom authentication system on top of SkylinkJS

Tags: webrtc

i'm building a website that uses WebRTC to share audio and video. Now i'd like to access WebRTC features on Android devices so i can create an app that can receives audio and video streams from the website.

I've looked for a technology allowing me to do that and I've found SkylinkJS.

It looks great but i'm wondering something. Can i build a custom authentication system on top of SkylinkJS logic. What i mean is that i'd like to make sure the connection to SkylinkJS rooms are initiated by users actually authenticated on my platform.

At the moment, i do that using socket.io but i can do it since i'm using raw WebRTC. How can i do that using SkylinkJS? Using the REST API?

Thanks.

PS: i cannot tag this question with 'skylinkjs' since it's a new tag, but it mights be cool if someone could do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can integrate that with the REST API in this [Applications REST API link here](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TPD/SkylinkAPI+-+Application+Resources?src=contextnavpagetreemode) - . You can generate your own credentials.

You can generate the connecting credentials from your server and then when the User logs in, generate the credentials for Users to connect to the Room. See more [in their support article](http://support.temasys.com.sg/support/solutions/articles/12000002712-authenticating-your-application-key-to-start-a-connection).

Answer (score 1):

SkylinkJS uses key based authentication mechanism to authenticate against the Temasys signaling servers. This ensures that any application using Skylink can only connect to calls in your application if the app can provide the same secure keys (from your Temasys developer account).

Your best bet in looping in Android would be to use the android counterpart. http://skylink.io/android/